# Increment the count with xpath

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I'm trying to add the tag named `<IND2-1-drug-count>`, i was successful in adding the the tag by using the XPathFactory API's.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<report>

    <IND2-1>
        <drug>
            <IND2-1-drug-count>1</IND2-1-drug-count>
            <B.4.k.12b>B.4.k.12b</B.4.k.12b>
            <B.4.k.14b>B.4.k.14b</B.4.k.14b>
            <B.4.k.15a>B.4.k.15a</B.4.k.15a>
            <B.4.k.11b>B.4.k.11b</B.4.k.11b>
        </drug> 
        <drug>
            <IND2-1-drug-count>1</IND2-1-drug-count>
            <B.4.k.14b>B.4.k.14b</B.4.k.14b>
            <B.4.k.15a>B.4.k.15a</B.4.k.15a>
            <B.4.k.11b>B.4.k.11b</B.4.k.11b>
        </drug> 

    </IND2-1>

    <IND2-1>
        <IND2-1-count>1</IND2-1-count>  
        <drug>
            <IND2-1-drug-count>2</IND2-1-drug-count>
            <B.4.k.12b>B.4.k.12b</B.4.k.12b>
            <B.4.k.14b>B.4.k.14b</B.4.k.14b>
            <B.4.k.15a>B.4.k.15a</B.4.k.15a>
            <B.4.k.11b>B.4.k.11b</B.4.k.11b>
        </drug> 
        <drug>
            <IND2-1-drug-count>2</IND2-1-drug-count>
            <B.4.k.14b>B.4.k.14b</B.4.k.14b>
            <B.4.k.15a>B.4.k.15a</B.4.k.15a>
            <B.4.k.11b>B.4.k.11b</B.4.k.11b>
        </drug> 
    </IND2-1>

</report>
```

But problem i'm facing is, if we look at the xml given above there are 2 occurrences of `<IND2-1>` tag, so when i do something like this

```
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/report/IND2-1/drug");
```

and try to create a text node, its creating the nodes as requried. But what i wanted is for the 1st occurence of `<IND2-1>` the value for that node to be 1, for 2nd occurrence 2 and so on.

Is there any way i can get the occurrence of `<IND2-1>` so that i can pass the same value for creating the node?

Comment: You are using XML wrong. If you have any chance, change the document structure to something generic. Element names are *not* supposed to be unique. Sensible would be something like [this](http://pastebin.com/Vxq5E7NS).

Comment: ok.. is it not at all possible in the existing way ? I'm using the same xml structure to generate report using the BIRT tool

Comment: Well, use `xpath.compile("/report/IND2-1[2]/drug[1]")` to get the first `drug` in the second `IND2-1`.

Comment: ok.. but i've added only 2 tags here.. but in real scenario it can grow.. so i'll first get the total count of the required tag and then loop through.. will that help ?

Comment: You get list of the actual elements (DOM nodes) and loop through *them*, getting each one individually with a custom XPath is horribly inefficient.

Comment: Can you explain the question a little more in detail? I don't understand what kind of node you're trying to create. A text node whose parent is `<drug>`?